# Positioning animated text in CSS3

Tags: html, css

my first question here. First of all english is not my native language so be patient if I'll do some mistake.

I've found a text animation that I like and I would add it to my site, here's the original version: http://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/lgybC

```css
@import "compass/css3";

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint);

body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 5vw/100vh "Finger Paint";
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 whitesmoke;
  animation: smoky 5s 3s both;
}

span:nth-child(even){
  animation-name: smoky-mirror;
}

@keyframes smoky {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    transform:
      translate3d(15rem,-8rem,0)
      rotate(-40deg)
      skewX(70deg)
      scale(1.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes smoky-mirror {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke; }
  to {
    transform:
      translate3d(18rem,-8rem,0)
      rotate(-40deg) 
      skewX(-70deg)
      scale(2);
     text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@for $item from 1 through 21 {
  span:nth-of-type(#{$item}){ 
    animation-delay: #{(3 + ($item/10))}s; 
  }
}
```

```html
<span>C</span><span>S</span><span>S</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>m</span><span>o</span><span>k</span><span>y</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>T</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>E</span><span>f</span><span>f</span><span>e</span><span>c</span><span>t</span>
```

Now, I'd like that after the first word/phrase disappears another one appears soon after at the same place using the reversed effect (from a smoky cloud appear the text).

I tried to edit the CSS to achive what I described above but without success.

Here is my edited version:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint);
body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 5vw/100vh "Finger Paint";
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.a span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 whitesmoke;
  animation: smoky 5s 3s both;
}

.a span:nth-child(even) {
  animation-name: smoky-mirror;
}

@keyframes smoky {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(15rem, -8rem, 0) rotate(-40deg) skewX(70deg) scale(1.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes smoky-mirror {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(18rem, -8rem, 0) rotate(-40deg) skewX(-70deg) scale(2);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.a span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

.a span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 3.2s;
}

.a span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 3.3s;
}

.a span:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 3.4s;
}

.a span:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.a span:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 3.6s;
}

.b span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 whitesmoke;
  animation: smoky 5s 3s both reverse;
}

.b span:nth-child(even) {
  animation-name: smoky-mirror;
}

@keyframes smoky {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(15rem, -8rem, 0) rotate(-40deg) skewX(70deg) scale(1.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes smoky-mirror {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(18rem, -8rem, 0) rotate(-40deg) skewX(-70deg) scale(2);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.b span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

.b span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 3.2s;
}

.b span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 3.3s;
}

.b span:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 3.4s;
}

.b span:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.b span:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 3.6s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Smoky Text</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="a"><span>U</span><span>m</span><span>b</span><span>r</span><span>i</span><span>a</span></div>
  <div class="b"><span>V</span><span>e</span><span>n</span><span>e</span><span>t</span><span>o</span></div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see there's something wrong in my edited CSS, in fact if you disable "overflow: hidden;" in the body element you'll see that the second word appears at the bottom of the browser and not at the same place of the first word.

Keep in mind I want to add the animated text in the header of my site so I'm looking for an easy way to easily position the words.

Is there someone willing to help me?

Thanks in advance!